# Is closures Object?

Tags: php, php-5.3

I am talking about Closures with some friends of a Group (from PHP 5.3).

When I do a `var_dump(function(){});` the result is `object(Closure)`. One of peoples said: but Closures are not Object.

I understand what when Anonymous Function implements Closure class, the result need to be a Object, nothing more or different.

Is a anonymous function a object?

**UPDATE**
I have read "Anonymous functions are implemented using the Closure class." (http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), so, I think this is a Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strongly worded in the manual:

> Anonymous functions, implemented in PHP 5.3, yield objects of this type [Closure]. This fact used to be considered an implementation detail, but it can now be relied upon.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php

To be clear, the answer is: yes, they are objects.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? In PHP `Closure` is a `final class`, so technically yes, it's an object.

Comment: Have you read my question? I am talking only. Not implementing.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't say if you're talking about trying to actually achieve something as part of a group project. If there was no goal you could've checked the documentation [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php).